# Opening same view in a new tab in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to open a view in a new tab exactly the way it is with all the css styles. i also have a sidebar menu and a horizontal menu, but those i do not need in the new tab. 
In my javascript function i have

```
var w = window.open();

$(w.document.body).html($("#form_name"));
```

This works not perfectly. it does pass all the properties, but does not have the styles. Also this erases everything from the main view.

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: with "a new tab" you mean a new browser tab?

Comment: could you supply some more details, please

Comment: yes, i mean a new browser tab

Comment: You have to create a new wrapper view containing just `#formname`

Comment: You would need to make a controller action that returns a partial view, then include all your styles in said partial view, and then in your main view, you would have an `a` link with `target='_blank'` set

Comment: why do i need a controller? isn't there any way that i can give the same styles to the new tab as my main view has (my main view already has all the styles i want)

Comment: Your styles are most likely included in the head of your page, but you're trying to send a little portion of the page. So you would need a separate partial view that has the styles and render that from your controller. Also, this is more my opinion, but I would always recommend to have a new window be opened with an `a` link, as many browsers block `window.open();` to prevent popups

Comment: i just don't have links, i work with ajax requests, and my url does not change. and i can't figure out what link i am supposed to open. and about my styles. they are all included in a separate .css file. is there any way that i can just link to it??